# How can I ensure the images will remain to the left of my text in an unordered list?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a contact page and I am having difficulty keeping the contact icons directly to the left of my text in the unordered list with the contactdetails ID. Additionally, despite being floated to the left some of the list items are placed horizontally next to each other.

Ideally I would like each list item to be on a separate line and for each image to be placed immediately to the left of the text sharing that li.

```css
    /* CSS Document */
    
    
    
    /*****COLOR*****/
    
    body{
     background-color: blue;
    }
    
    header{
     background-color: #8DC641;
    }
    
    nav{
     background-color: #FFF;
    }
    
    nav ul li a{
     color: olive;
    }
    
    nav ul li a:hover{
     background-color: #2DC4A6;
     color: #FFF;
    }
    
    .content{
     background-color: #FFF;
    }
    
    footer{
     background-color: #FFF;
    }
    
    
    
    /*****BODY*****/
    
    body{
     background: url("../Images/bodyBackground/bodyBackground.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
     max-width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
    }
    
    
    
    /*****WRAPPER*****/
    
    .wrapper{
     width: 70%;
     height: 100%;  /* Height adjusts to Wrapper content */
     margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    
    
    /*****HEADER*****/
    
    header{
     height: 120px;
     margin: 0 ;
    }
    
    #headerLogo{
      width: 110px;
     height: 90%;
      margin-left: 20px;
     padding-top: 5px;
    }
    
    #headerLogo img{
     max-height: 100%;
      border-radius: 30px;
    }
    
    
    
    /*****NAVIGATION*****/
    
    nav{
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
     margin: 0;
     border-top: 5px solid #3DB54A;
     border-bottom: 5px solid #3DB54A;
     font-size: 1.40em
    }
    
    nav ul{; /* Navigation menu */
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    nav ul li{
      list-style-type: none;
      float: left;
     border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    nav ul li a{
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     padding: 12px 20px;
    }
    
    #homenav{ /* Right border for "Home" nav button */
     border-left: 1px solid black;
     margin-left: 60px;
    }
    
    
    
    /*****CONTENT*****/
    
    .content{
     width: 100%;
     height: 600px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    .content p{
     width: 70%;
     padding-top: 30px;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    
    
    /*****CONTACT CONTENT*****/
    
    #contactdetails{
     max-width: 400px;
     height: 600px;
    }
    
    #contactdetails ul{; /* Navigation menu */
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #contactdetails ul li{
      list-style-type: none;
      float: left;
    }
    
    
    /***FOOTER***/
    
    footer{
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 0 auto;
     border-top: 5px solid #3DB54A;
     border-bottom: 5px solid #3DB54A;
    }
    
    footer ul{
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
    }
    
    footer li{
     display: inline-block;
     margin-right: 10%;
     padding-top: 13px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html><!-- InstanceBegin template="Templates/SiteTemplate.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
    
    <head>
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
    <title>Darren's Web Assignment</title>
    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    <link href="CSS/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div class = "wrapper"> <!--begin Wrapper-->
    
     <header> <!--begin Header-->
      <div id = "headerLogo">
          <img src="Images/headerLogo/headerLogo.PNG" alt="Greenery-logo" />
      </div>
     </header> <!--end Header-->
    
      <nav> <!--begin mainNav -->
       <ul>
        <li id = "homenav"><a href = "index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "products.html">Products</a></li>
       <li><a href = "about.html">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href = "contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
      </nav> <!--end mainNav-->
    
      <div class = "content"> <!--begin Content--><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="editableContent" -->
      <div id = "contactdetails">
       <ul>
         <li><p><img src = "Images/icons/png/houseicon.png" alt = "Address icon">23 Kingfisher Court, Werribee 3030, Victoria</p></li>
         <li><p><img src = "Images/icons/png/emailicon.png" alt = "Email icon">contact@greenery.com</p></li>
        <li><p><img src = "Images/icons/png/phoneicon.png" alt = "Phone icon">0397488945</p></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- InstanceEndEditable --></div> <!--end Content-->
    
      <footer> <!--begin Footer-->
        <ul>
         <li><a href = "about.html">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href = "about.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href = "about.html">Site Map</a></li>
        </ul>
      </footer> <!--end Footer-->
    
    </div> <!--end Wrapper -->
    </body>
    
    <!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

Comment: try putting a <br style='clear:both'> between each of the <li> elements

Comment: Your statements are a bit confusing. Can you clarify your question? You want the image to be above your text, you want your image to be above and to the left of your text, or you want your image to be to the left of your text, but not immediately to the left?

Comment: I would like my image to be immediately left of my text.

Comment: Please, next time, extract exactly the part that does not work, try to make it work in a seperate file, and if that does not work then post that minified version on Stack Overflow so we can work with minimal code and don't get distracted by irrelevant code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following css:

```
#contactdetails ul li img {
    display: inline-block;
}

#contactdetails ul li p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Arrange your html like this:

```
<div id = "contactdetails">
   <ul>
       <li>
           <img src = "Images/icons/png/houseicon.png" alt = "Address icon" />
           <p>23 Kingfisher Court, Werribee 3030, Victoria</p>
       </li>
       <li>
           <img src = "Images/icons/png/emailicon.png" alt = "Email icon" />
           <p>contact@greenery.com</p>
       </li>
       <li>
           <img src = "Images/icons/png/phoneicon.png" alt = "Phone icon" />
           <p>0397488945</p>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```